# Shell access on a webhost via PHP

Tags: php, ssh, web-hosting

I've seen people uploading `.php` files that give them command line access to a server by loading `http://example.com/cli`, similar to SSH, could you give me an example?

A client bought a shared hosting account from a web host that does not allow `ssh` and forces me to use cPanel. I abhor cPanel, it cripples my productivity by making me click around and wait for it to load a bloated gui. What I hate more is that i have to download files and then upload them to the host instead of a `wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just ignore the unexplained downvotes this question received and keep it up because this might help someone else in the future:

Most people I've seen have called it a web based shell, or a php shell. It lets you execute arbitrary shell commands on php servers. Here are a few projects I've found:

1. PHP Shell: http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/
2. b374k: https://github.com/b374k/b374k

Just be sure to use a password, and to delete the shell when you're done so that someone doesn't accidentally find it in the future.